# Imgura won't install because of an error

Tags: apps, store, 8.1

When I want to install Imgura app I get an error code *8103012e*.

[image]

Can someone tell me what to do? I searched the web for explanation  to this error and found nothing.

Comment: Have you retried, or is this consistent?

Comment: In the launch day of Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview the Store had experience an error like that. The problem still occurs?

Comment: This problem remains after the store problems. I tried to install this app several times and it always shows this error.

Comment: I just installed with no problem.

Comment: I tried that too and no problem installing that app. @Potek, is the problem still remaining? If not, this Q should be closed, IMO.

Comment: Yes, somehow the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

The error code `8103012e` may occur due to the following **reasons** :

1. *Improper language and regional combination* : For example, if you have set your region to US and does not have English(US) language installed on your phone.
2. *Not able to install on your SD card* : Some apps will not install on SDcard.
3. *Improper date and time sync*

Some common **solutions** to resolve this error is:

1. Make sure your Region and Language settings are set correctly.
2. Change default install location of app to Phone in Storage sense.
3. [Set Date and time](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/change-date-and-time) manually and Restart the phone.

**References** :

1. [Error 8103012e - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdapps/error-code-8103012e/326543ae-6e6b-4093-8f85-979d1f4f746a)
2. [8103012e.....what can i do? - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdapps/8103012ewhat-can-i-do/96d9d59d-e200-41b9-8f0e-420a52d9dcd7)
3. [How do I fix Error Code-8103012e - Windows central](https://forums.windowscentral.com/ask-question/318432-how-do-i-fix-error-code-8103012e-when-trying-update-truecaller-app.html)